# Why does my span stay the same color of its parenting div?

Tags: css, background-color, html

I wrote the following code, including a div and a span. I want the span inside the div to have a different colour, but it doesnt seem to work.. This is the html code:

```
    <div class="menu">
        <p class="menuHeader">Menu</p>
        <ul class="menuList">
            <li><a href="">Inspiration</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Motivation</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Decision</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Solution</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Action</a></li>
        </ul>

        <span id="decorationBox">
        <br/>
        </span>
    </div>
```

In CSS I set the background color of the div 'menu' to a dark blue color, and the background color of the span 'decorationBox' to a lighter blue color. I also tried using a higher z-index to bring the span up to the front, but it wont display. Is it because of the span being inside the div?

Comment: Seems to work, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AjkBD/).

Comment: @Vucko You placed text within the `<span>`. That's the actual problem the OP is having. Empty `<span>` don't have a width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any 'real' content in the `<span>`, therefore it won't (at least with default CSS settings) be displayed.

Setting `display` to `block` would make the width fit to the parent width:

[→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybAdW/1/)

```
span#decorationBox {
    background-color: red;

    /* the default setting is "display: inline" for <span>s */
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Indeed. And if the intention is for the span to be a "box", as seems to be implied by the id, perhaps it should have been a `<div>` (which are blocks by default) all along.

Answer (score 1):

Most of CSS properties does not work properly with span. Try to use a div instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your span width is 0px. Place content in the span and you will see. With the `br` tag, you just have 18px on height in the span.

You can add property `display:block;` on span to see the difference.

> The  tag is used to group **inline**-elements in a document.

Answer (score 0):

`span` is an inline tag by default, it doesn't have width or height properties, so if it is empty you cannot see it as bold or italic... You can change span to div or give block property in css:

```
.decorationBox {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="menu">
    <p class="menuHeader">Menu</p>
    <ul class="menuList">
        <li><a href="">Inspiration</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Motivation</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Decision</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Solution</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Action</a></li>
    </ul>

    <span id="decorationBox">
        Content here.
    </span>
</div>
```

Css

```
div.menu {
    background-color: blue;
}
.menu #decorationBox {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
}
```

OR

```
div.menu{background:blue;}
.menu span{background-color:red;}
```

Ex. http://jsfiddle.net/2NwmU/1/